# Can a large npy file be converted into small npy files?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large npy file with 33,696 lines of data. I would like to separate this into 18 small files with 1872 lines of data in each. I have tried to use the same codes for converting a large text file into small text files but I am not able to receive the output that I want. What alternative codes can be used to achieve this?

I tried to repeat the same steps as done for the text file but did not receive the output that I wanted.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to share an example of what kind of data is in this file, because Serge's answer should work perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by `lines of data`?  A proper `npy` file is binary, so doesn't have lines.  An array stored in such a file may have that many "rows", but you have to know that before hand.  You can't deduce that from the file.  Are you sure this file was created with a `np.save`?

Answer (score 1):

A npy file is a binary format file that must be loaded as a whole. On the other hand, a text file should be read one line at a time. That means that you cannot expect that a code expecting text file to correctly process **binary** npy files.

Here you should:

1. load the npy file into a large numpy array (`numpy.load`)
2. split the large numpy array into smaller ones
3. save the smaller files

Possible code:

```
arr = np.load('large_file')
for rank, start in range(0, 33696, 1872):
   np.save(f'small_{rank}.npy', arr[start: start+1872])
```

Comment: Received the following error when I tried to use your codes ```ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False```  When I changed the first line to ```arr = np.load('large_file'), allow_pickle=True``` I received another error ```_pickle.UnpicklingError: Failed to interpret file 'large_file' as a pickle``` What needs to be changed to avoid such errors and receive the ouput that I want?

Comment: @Mohamed: **you** said it was a npy file. The error is a hint that it is probably not...

Comment: The following is my whole code: ```import numpy as np

arr = np.load("out_1.npy")
for rank, start in range(0, 33696, 1872):
   np.save(f'small_{rank}.npy', arr[start: start+1872])```